# Pass label value from ASPX to ASCX page

Tags: asp.net

How do i pass the value (ID or text) of a label in a ASPX page to "Web User Control(ASCX)" page?
Answers with code are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151323/how-to-pass-value-between-user-control-in-asp-net-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You have to write one "string" property in User Control. To which you need to pass value from your aspx page. For example refer below code;

## In UserControl ##

```
<style type="text/css">
.MyDiv
{
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
</style>
<div class="MyDiv">
<asp:Label ID="lblShow" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="WhiteSmoke"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

### In UserControl's Code Behind

```
private string SValue;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return SValue; }
        set { SValue = value; }
    }
    #endregion
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblShow.Text = Value.ToString();
    }
```

Now you have to Drag and Drop your user control to your aspx page which will look like below;

### In aspx Page

```
<div>
<uc1:ControlToDisplayValue runat="server" id="ControlToDisplayValue" />
</div>
```

### In aspx PageLoad Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ControlToDisplayValue.Value = Label1.Text;
    }
```

Hope this is helpful to you :)